# How to convert text to a reference

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010 does not update hyperlink references when previous rows to the destination are added or deleted unlike excel XP.  I can create a reference as text by searching for the proper cell on another sheet but hyperlinks do NOT accept text as a reference.  INDIRECT does not work since hypertext then takes the value at the destination as the reference.

Comment: Is there a question in your statement or are you just venting frustration? This issue would be a lot easier to understand if you added a few examples to illustrate. For e.g. What are "previous rows to the destination"??